# Do Norway, Sweden, Iceland, Germany and Austria disallow the official registration of electoral alliances (instead of their constituent parties)?

Tags: voting-systems, proportional-representation

It seems to me that minimum election thresholds in Bulgaria, Slovenia, Czechia, Poland, Latvia, and Israel function to reduce risk of political gridlock due to fragmentation (which can compound political crises, as seen in eg Weimar-era Germany) but large numbers of very small parties in these countries can group themselves as electoral alliances to get over the threshold. The parliamentary representation of fragmented alliances exacerbates an unhealthy level of political fragmentation in Israel and Bulgaria, contributing to frequent political gridlock, crisis, and early elections in those two countries.

Electoral alliances intended to get member parties over an electoral threshold are not a feature of politics in New Zealand or Germanic countries such as Norway, Sweden, Iceland, Germany, and Austria. Do they have any specific laws/restrictions which disallow registering several small parties as a single electoral alliance for an election? If so, have such rules been considered and rejected for any reason by countries where fragmented alliances contribute to fragmented politics, such as Bulgaria?

(Appendix: I understand that constituent parties of the long-standing coalitions CDU-CSU in modern Germany and The Alliance in Sweden have always registered separately for elections, so they are not 'electoral alliances' in the way I am using the term and have never protected member parties from the risk of running afoul of the electoral threshold.)

Comment: As I understand it, parties in Germany can ally but they must individually cross the threshold. The 5% limit is not a 5% limit, it is 5%-or-plurality-in-three-districts which was never a problem for the CSU or CDU ...

Comment: "re intended to reduce risk of political gridlock due to fragmentation" the device was first used in Germany and was motivated primarily by preventing extremists parties from getting a voice in politics (with Soviet style communism and Nazism being the main concerns). Gridlock was a secondary consideration. Also, are you sure about Israel? If it has a threshold, it is very low which is why it is so fragmented politically.

Comment: I would say that fragmentation within alliances is the primary cause of overall fragmentation in Bulgaria. It is a secondary contributing factor to fragmentation in Israel, where 13 parties  are represented currently. Joint list (3 parties) and United Torah Judaism (2 parties) increase the number of parties represented to 16.

Comment: I didn't know that about the intention behind the threshold in Germany, but I would add that a threshold wouldn't work that way in the US, UK, or Germany, where extremists get into mainstream parties through entryism and can even end up hijacking them (eg the AfD). I think the main function of the threshold in Germanic countries and New Zealand is to reduce fragmentation, not exclude extremists, so I'll rephrase to make clear it's my opinion (because it's unclear that it's the opinion of people who design the electoral systems).

Answer (score 4):

At least for Germany, the election law (Bundeswahlgesetz) is pretty clear in that:

- only single parties may submit (state) lists; a party may submit at most one list per state

  (this derives from the phrasing of [§27](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/bwahlg/__27.html) which implies single parties)
- only the lists of a single party are considered when determining whether they crossed the 5 % threshold; and only district mandates of candidates of a single party are considered when determining whether they received 3 district mandates to exempt them from the 5 % requirement (*Grundmandatsklausel*).

  (explicit in [§6(3)](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/bwahlg/__6.html).)

So yes, at a federal level Germany disallows both multiple parties registering a joint list and multiple party lists being combined for the purposes of crossing the threshold.

(While a list must always be nominated by one party – meaning that one party's leadership is responsible – the party may choose to name candidates for this list who belong to other parties. For example, in 2005 the then Linkspartei.PDS (Left Party.PDS) permitted members of the party WASG (formed mostly of former SPD members) to run for election on the Linkspartei.PDS list. The parties merged in 2007. Historically, there have been more such instances but they were less successful.)

At a state level, it depends on the state election system. I do not have time to go through all 16. Furthermore, at a local level there are another 13–16 election systems (unsure about the city states). I do not have time to go into those in detail either.

I do recall, however, that in Bavarian municipal elections election alliances (considering two lists as one list for seat distribution purposes) was permitted at least in 2008. This actually was beneficial for smaller parties as there was no threshold but seats were distributed according to the D'Hont method. By combining lists, smaller parties could leverage the D'Hont advantage larger parties have; the seats between them were distributed by the size-blind Hare-Niemeyer system. The system has lost its usefulness since D'Hont is no longer used for Bavarian local elections.

I cannot comment on the situation in the other countries you mentioned.

---

A final note on the CDU/CSU thing: this is all based on a gentlemen's agreement of the CDU not running in Bavaria and the CSU *only* running in Bavaria. A couple of times the CSU has tried threatening the CDU with running nationwide but they never did. For election purposes, they are treated as two completely separate parties. Meaning:

- Each party individually must clear the 5 % threshold or gain 3 district mandates

  (The CSU has typically comfortably cleared the threshold even though they only ran in one state; however, they also comfortably won more than 3 district mandates in every federal election)
- If the CDU wins 45 % of the vote share and the CSU wins 6 %, the majority clause does not apply. If the SPD were to win 51 %, the majority clause *would* apply.

  (This clause states that if due to some peculiarity a party that won an absolute majority of votes did not win an outright majority of seats they gain additional seats to reach that outright majority. Plus a handful of technicalities.)

In parliament, parties are free to associate into fractions as they please, so a joint CDU/CSU fraction was never a problem.

Answer (score 0):

In Austria, it seems that such an alliance might be kind of feasible, according to [this government website (only in German, translation below)](https://www.oesterreich.gv.at/themen/leben_in_oesterreich/wahlen/1/Seite.320250.html):

> Wahlwerbende Parteien
>
> Wahlwerbende Parteien sind Wählergruppen, die sich mit einer eindeutigen Parteibezeichnung und einem Wahlvorschlag zur Wahl stellen. Sie sind meist mit den politischen Parteien identisch. Allerdings kann sich eine wahlwerbende Gruppe auch nur anlässlich einer Wahl bilden und muss nicht zugleich eine politische Partei sein. In rechtlicher Hinsicht besteht der Unterschied zwischen wahlwerbenden und politischen Parteien darin, dass bei Wahlen nur wahlwerbende Gruppen (Wahlparteien) und keine politischen Parteien antreten.

DeepL translation:

> Electoral campaigning parties
>
> Electoral campaigning parties are groups of voters who stand for election with a unique party name and an election proposal. They are usually identical with political parties. However, an electoral group can also be formed only on the occasion of an election and does not have to be a political party at the same time. From a legal point of view, the difference between electoral and political parties is that only electoral groups (electoral parties) and not political parties run in elections.

The members would have to agree on a name and a list of candidates, but there doesn't need to be any formal connection to a political party.

Comment: But the question is multiple political parties could form a single "Wahlwerbende Gruppe (Whalpartei)". It doesn't become clear, but they actually might.

Comment: Well, I can't think of any law that would prevent it. It seems that at least one group (I had never heard of them before - seems like a collection of fringe groups) is actively trying to form such an alliance (https://wahlbuendnis.at/), although they are themselves registered as a political party, so I'm not sure they are a valid example.

Comment: Sounds like alliances could run as a wahlebewerbende Gruppe & split up for votes in parliament. If conditions developed allowing this tactic to catch on (as in BGR), it could defeat the purpose of the threshold, inducing a self-reinforcing spiral of: - increasing numbers of cohesive voting blocs, blocs needed for a coalition, & potential coalition combinations - more diffuse/less transparent negotiations with diluted success criteria, reducing accountability - worsening quality of governance/voter satisfaction/vote fragmentation. Is any identifiable factor restraining this practice in Austria?

Comment: Well, splitting up after being elected does occasionally happen with political parties as well. The FPÖ lost their liberal wing (split off into ""Liberales Forum"), later another group split off as "BZÖ". The Green party lost the members of the "Liste Pilz" (and subsequently fell below the 4% threshold in the next election, but are back now, even part of the current government. "Team Stronach" dissolved, etc. Usually, only one of the remaining parts survives longer than the next few rounds of elections.